# How to implement long scrolling behaviour

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

So I'm creating a portfolio of my work and I wanted to implement some form of long scrolling similar to this: https://blocksphere.co/#home

I've been reading some articles on how to get this behaviour right and come across CSS snap scrolling but this just seems to guide the user to the nearest container rather than snap and pause.

I need a simple example of how to implement this behaviour as I'm a bit stumped as to whether this behaviour is achieved by JS or pure CSS.

Thanks in advance.

Sources: https://css-tricks.com/introducing-css-scroll-snap-points/

Comment: Nothing to do with regard to your problem, in my opinion, this scrolling system is not very user-friendly because it's not enough responsive to the mouse.

Comment: Is a pure css solution. https://css-tricks.com/practical-css-scroll-snapping/. The js part is there for implementing the functionality in older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pure CSS solution, as outlined in the codepen that is presented on the link you provided. The browser support for this method of scrolling is not the greatest in older/legacy browser so they "Polyfill" it for those browser using JavaScript code. Polyfilling means that you forcefully implement a modern behaviour/feature that is not natively implemented in the browser.